# QtCreator creates unwanted windows

Tags: 13.04, qt, c++, qml, qt-creator

This issue occurs on raring with the build "qtcreator 2.8.1-0ubuntu1~raring1~test1", the latest from the software center. It works fine in general, but if you click on "Welcome" and than on "Develop", "Examples" or "Tutorials" some unwanted windows appear. Here is an image of the behaviour:

[image]

Furthermore, there is a specific pattern. If you click on "Develop", four windows appear. If you click on "Examples", two windows appear. And if you click on "Tutorials", one window appears. After that, you can't use the IDE anymore. Sometimes I have to kill the process with kill on the terminal.

Except from this issue everything works fine. You can create projects, modify code, build it and run it.

Comment: Ok, the issue is fixed with the official version of QtCreator from qt-project [qt-project](http://qt-project.org). Sadly this doesn't offer a nice integreation with Unity, but it is the latest version. The bug with the version occurs also on the new 13.10.

Comment: This bug is still there. It was filed into launchpad months ago and a couple of users (like me) signalled it again in March, April and May 2014, both on Ubuntu and on some derivative (my Linux Mint 14, e.g.). Apparently, it is a deep bug, quite hard to fix. See launchpad for details.

Comment: I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 14.04 a few days ago. If you install the official SDK from the Software Center everything works. The only thing that is not delivered by default is the documentation (including the examples) but you can install them afterwards.