# 13.10 qtcreateor 271 wont work

Tags: 13.10, qt

Just installed ubuntu 13.10 x86 with all updates. I then installed qt4 libraries and qt creator 271:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
sudi apt-get install qtcreator
```

Both installed successfully, and i can launch qt creator, but then i get a black window when i switch to "examples" or "development":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjPX.png

The windows cannot be closed.
I am guessing  because qtcreator somehow cannot find the qt version i installed. This is the settings page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rojhy.png

what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you're not the first with this problem. I asked this question before [in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361011/qtcreator-creates-unwanted-windows) and [in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449631/qtcreator-creates-unwanted-windows). I even filled a report it on launchpad.

I did much research about it but I didn't find any solution for that. Now I am using the offical qtcreator from [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/downloads). The advantage is that examples and tutorials are available and you have the latetst documentation installed which is one of the best resources to learn everything about Qt-Programming. And, of course, you have the latest version of Qt. The only problem with this is that the offical version lacks nice Ubuntu integration, but this is really acceptable.

Comment: is there any way i can get that installer for qt4? I have a large qt4 app at hand, and i am not exactly dying to port it over to qt5 right now...

Comment: Look on the official site. There could be a link like "Older versions".

Comment: yeah, but not for the installer. *sigh* who knew it was so hard? Might look into building the project command line style.